# trying to do GUI using C

Tags: c, user-interface

I'm trying to write code for little GUI in C.
my code is :

```
#include <stdgui.h>

CALLBACK(draw_hello, evt, param)
{
int ascent, descent;
FONT fnt;

fnt = get_appfont();
get_font_info(fnt, &ascent, &descent, NULL);
plot_str(evt->graphic, 5, 5+ascent+descent, "Hello World", fnt);

return 0;
}

int main(int args, char *arg[])
{
int rv;

start_gui("Hello", args, arg, 0,
    DEF_CB, "draw_hello", draw_hello, DONE);

create_window("Hello", 0, 0, 200, 100, 0,
    SET_PROP, "ON_REDRAW", 1, "draw_hello", DONE);

run_event_loop(&rv);

return rv;
```

}

but its showing error :
gui.c:1:20: fatal error: stdgui.h: No such file or directory...
what to do..?

Also i tried GTK first but its very difficult to install.
I'm tired of doing that and needed very small gui so shifted to the stdgui.
Any help in that issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Clearly you don't have `stdgui.h`. Not a big deal - I don't have it either, and have no ideas what library it supposed to mean. What OS? What library you're trying to use?

Comment: "shifted to the stdgui" — have you installed it? How? What OS? What compiler?

Comment: @keltar Believe it or not, it belongs to "StdGUI" library. And I personally prefer to stay away from everything non-standard that has a name implying that it actually is a standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no header file called stdgui.h and there is no standard GUI. You will need to find a framework which will allow you to make GUIs. I used tk/tcl a long time ago but there are other previous answers see ([Introduction to GUI programming with c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852130/introduction-to-gui-programming-with-c)). We are not really supposed to recommend frameworks to use.